# How to set an AlarmManager for preselected days?

Tags: android, widget, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm creating an alarm widget, and it works, however, I'm currently using it for a single day, I'd like to know how to define it for predefined days, let's say for example I want to setup the alarman for monday, wednesday and friday, how can I accomplish that?

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, dPicker.getYear());
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, dPicker.getMonth());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tPicker.getCurrentHour());
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tPicker.getCurrentMinute());
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);   

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), testThis(this));
```

I'm currently using a TimePicker and a DatePicker, but I will change the design to use checkboxes, each per day, but I'm not sure how to define the alarm for the selected days, any help? thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Defining them at once i don't know if this can be achieved, but i have another scenario to use.
Say that you adjusted the Alarm to fire on Monday, Tuesday , Thursday. you will adjust the **AlarmManager** just for Monday and on Monday it should fire and checks for the next alarm ( which will be on Tuesday ) and so on. Save all you alarms in a database and take them out one be one and in each alarm check for the next one ( if exists )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK) api like this:

```
cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,2);  //monday
cal2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,4);  //wednesday
cal3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,6);  //friday
```

and sets 3 alarmMgr like this:

```
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, testThis(this));  // every monday
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, testThis(this));  // every wednesday
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7, testThis(this));  // every friday
```

Comment: I might try this, in a for loop depending on how many checkboxes are marked in my application; I have a question: when you turn off the phone, are these AlarmManager instances "deleted"? I mean, will the setup be deleted? thanks!

Comment: In Android developer Api you can read the following: Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep (and can optionally wake the device up if they go off during that time), but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.