# How do I setup AlarmManager for different days?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I have almost finished a little alarm application in Android, it works fine, however, right now it only works to setup an alarm only for one day, but the design has been made to select different days, for example (monday, wednesday, friday). This is the way I setup the alarm:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

//tPicker is a TimePicker
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tPicker.getCurrentHour());
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tPicker.getCurrentMinute());
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);   

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent(this));

//pIntent method
public static PendingIntent pIntent(Context context){
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("myAlarm.intent.action.CLOCK");

return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

It works great as I said, but I don't know how to setup an alarm for each day I select in the application, I would appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: look at this example http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/10/schedule-repeating-alarm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the alarm manager 3 times (in case monday, wednesday and friday are selected).

Code stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19298186/2829009:

```
cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,2);  //monday
cal2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,4);  //wednesday
cal3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,6);  //friday
```

and then set the an alarm manager for every day:

```
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent(this)); 
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent(this));  
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal3.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent(this));
```

**Edit:**

```
private static final MONDAY = 2;
private static final WEDNESDAY = 4;
private static final FRIDAY = 6;

Calendar calMonday = Calendar.getInstance();

//tPicker is a TimePicker
calMonday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tPicker.getCurrentHour());
calMonday.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tPicker.getCurrentMinute());
calMonday.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calMonday.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); 

//now copy you calendar for the other days
Calendar calWednesday = calMonday.clone();
Calendar calFriday = calMonday.clone();

//set week days
calMonday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, MONDAY);
calWednesday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, WEDNESDAY); 
calFriday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, FRIDAY); 

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calMonday.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent(this, MONDAY));
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calWednesday.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent(this, WEDNESDAY));
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calFriday.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent(this, FRIDAY));

//pIntent method
public static PendingIntent pIntent(Context context, int id){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("myAlarm.intent.action.CLOCK");

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent,    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Comment: As I previously asked, in this case, does that mean to use a different AlarmManager, Calendar instance or just the id passed to the PendingIntent needs to be different? thanks!

Comment: you just need 3 different calendar instances... but if you later want for example to stop one alarm, your intents need to be different. then you need to pass an id to each pendingintent

Comment: So, I can use the same method for the PendingIntent, with the same action(?) but to pass a different id every time, am I right? thanks.

Comment: I'll give it a try asap and post my results, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need different PendingIntents for each alarm you want. From the docs:

> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
>   the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
>   at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something
>   that is different about them to associate them with different
>   PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by
>   Intent.filterEquals, or different request code integers supplied to
>   getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int,
>   Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or
>   getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

For example, change this line:

```
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, MONDAY, intent,    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

where MONDAY is a static integer.

Comment: Do I need to use different Calendar and AlarManager instances for each day or just the PendingIntent id must be different? thanks!